# Convolution product of affine flag variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I know the definition of convolution product in D.Gaitsgory's paper, but I can give a convolution product

$p:G(K)\times Fl \to Fl\times Fl$,$q:G(K)\times Fl \to G(K)\times_{G(O)} Fl$, $m:G(K)\times_{G(O)} Fl \to Fl$

$A_1,A_2\in P_I (Fl)$,$A_1*A_2=Rm^* A$ ,$q^* A=p^*(A_1\times A_2)$

**Does this  definition coincide with the Gaitsgory's sense?**

Comment: Gaitsgory has more than one paper, so it would be helpful if your reference were more precise. 

Answer (score 1):

This has been defined in Gaitsgory's article  "Construction of central elements in the affine Hecke algebra via nearby cycles" : http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9912074.